# Want to construct Build name in Jenkins using multiple strings fetched from SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

In one of Continuous Integration activity, we are looking for setting a build name for Jenkins job (using Build Name plugin) by concatenating couple of strings. 
- Application Version Number [Its a string from properties file from SVN]
- Revision Number [SVN Revision Number]

Looking to export these strings as a environment variable so can be accessed across job.
Any ideas how can these strings made available in Jenkins job as a Environment Variable?

Answer (score 0):

The Subversion Plugin exports the revision number as `SVN_REVISION`environment variable, see the [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-SubversionRevisionandURLinformationasEnvironmentVariables) for details.

And you can use the EnvInject plugin to export all properties from a properties file as environment variables. Again, see the [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-InjectvariablesafteraSCMcheckout) for details.

Comment: Agreed. But the problem is, I want the Revision number and Version number of different module than the one I am checking out.

Comment: You can checkout multiple modules and then use the `SVN_REVISION_n` variable. The wiki page says "The Subversion SCM plugin exports the svn revisions and URLs of the build's subversion modules as environment variables. These are $SVN_REVISION_n and $SVN_URL_n, where n is the 1-based index of the module in the configuration."